# How to "report" a user

Tags: support, flagging

We can flag posts in WPSE, whether it's spam or something.

Today I found a registered user like: [user:equipment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47829/epuiqment) is a spammer. But couldn't flag the account.

But how to "Report" a user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag one of the user’s posts, use the custom flag reason to explain the problem.

In case of spam accounts, flagging the spam content once is enough. We will see those flags and destroy the account anyway. I just did that.